# vi substitute in json

Tags: regex, vim

I have a JSON file which has a bunch of jpg references that I'm trying to replace with png. I want to match on a pattern where there is a double digit and period before the jpg, capture 1, and use it in the replacement. The issue is I only ever get pattern not found.

```
"plith":"img/01.jpg"},{"block_ha....
```

where the substitution code looks like the following

```
:%s/\(\d{2}\.\)+jpg/$1png/g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this substitution command:

```
:%s/\v(\d{2}\.)jpg/\1png/g
```

And it replaced the line:

```
"plith":"img/01.jpg"},{"block_ha....
```

With:

```
"plith":"img/01.png"},{"block_ha....
```

If the 2 digits and the following dot can be repeated, you can apply the `+` quantifier to `\d{2}\.`:

```
:%s/\v(\d{2}\.)+jpg/\1png/g
```

---

In your original command:

```
:%s/(\d{2}.)+jpg/$1png/g
```

There seemed to be 3 problems:

1. you use non-escaped parentheses to capture the digits, but by default you need to escape them. If you don't want to, you can switch to very magic mode by adding the atom `\v` in your pattern.
2. you don't escape the `.`, which means that it will match any character (except a newline), instead of a literal dot
3. in the replacement part, you use `$1` to refer to the first capturing group, but it should be `\1`

Comment: You might also consider using `\zs` to set that start of the match inside the substitution. e.g `:%s/\d\d\.\zsjpg/png/g`. See `:h /\zs` for more information.